How to rewrite the destination IP address in OpenWRT?
I'm using OpenWRT 23.05 and I have following situation:

Local server in network lan, accessible via port 80, 443 on IP 10.150.42.7
My PC, on the same network
My Phone, on the same network
My sister's phone, lives somewhere else

I gave my sister access to the server mentioned above using Tailscale. I have set up a public DNS record which points to the Tailscale IP 100.76.72.54. I have also configured HTTPs using Caddy on the server.
This way my sister can access the server via Tailscale and just has to enter the public domain name which works fine.
The domain name I use locally and in the public internet is the same and I wish that to stay that way. I am not going to configure a second domain, otherwise I have to keep changing the configuration on my portable devices.
On my OpenWRT router I have configured that the DNS name should be resolved internally to the internal IP 10.150.42.7, which works fine (I tested it with dig).
However, the problem is due to DNSSEC being enabled in the browser on my PC, it does not use the internal resolver and rather forcefully uses the public DNS resolver and thus gets the Tailscale IP. Since my PC is not connected to Tailscale at all times (and I don't want to change this) and I also don't want to disable DNSSEC on all devices in my network, I want to rewrite the IP in OpenWRT.
How do I configure OpenWRT (LuCI preferred) so that the destination IP address 100.76.72.54 is rewritten to 10.150.42.7 in the network lan?
I have tried following things:
Port Forward

But here I can only specify where to route the traffic to but not what the "original" IP is, so this would just redirect everything.
Traffic Rules

I can't specify "forward" in "Action" so this is not the right place.
NAT Rules

Here I can specify a "Rewrite IP address" but there is no "DNAT" choice in "Action".
Static route

I can specify the IP address (using /32) and the Gateway but it won't actually rewrite the destination IP address but rather just route it to the Gateway which has no idea what to do with it (which is already the case since the 100.* addresses would have no destination in the first place)

so is it valid to summarize your issue as you want to use the public IP (tailscale) to access the service when you are both inside and outside the LAN, but its not working when you are inside, and you don't want to use split horizon DNS. is that correct? if so have you tried enabling NAT hairpinning/loopback/reflection?

Yes, that's correct, and I don't want to rely on Tailscale to make my internal network work.

Rewriting the destination address is DNAT, and DNAT is the Port Forwarding section in OpenWrt. You can specify additional criteria, including "External IP address", in the Advanced tab. I've just tried it on a RutOS device and it did not work, unfortunately, but it might work on plain OpenWrt.
(Since you're setting up a lan→lan NAT rule, you will probably want "NAT Loopback" to be enabled as well.)
But if the frontend doesn't let you configure it, then you will need to write the rules by hand (older versions with iptables have a "Custom Rules" tab; newer versions apparently use nftables).
I'm not able to finish the rules since I don't know the table and chain names that OpenWrt uses, but it would look somewhat like this for iptables (Fw3):
# Translate destination
iptables -t nat -I [TODO: chain name] -d 100.76.72.54 -j DNAT --dnat-to 10.150.42.7

# Translate source (NAT hairpinning)
iptables -t nat -I [TODO: chain name] -s 10.150.42.0/24 -d 10.150.42.7 -j MASQUERADE

(Standard chains would be PREROUTING for DNAT rules and POSTROUTING for SNAT rules, but OpenWrt has a ton of custom ones as can be seen in iptables-save. I would first add "partial" rules via GUI, then dump them via SSH to see which chain they went into.)
...and for nftables (Fw4), which it seems needs to be injected like this:
table [TODO: table name (probably "inet nat")] {
    chain [TODO: chain name] {
        ip daddr 100.76.72.54 dnat to 10.150.42.7
    }
    chain [TODO: chain name] {
        ip saddr 10.150.42.0/24 ip daddr 10.150.42.7 masquerade
    }
}

(Nftables has no standard chain names so you pretty much have to look through nft list ruleset.)

I can't specify "forward" in "Action" so this is not the right place.

Even if it were the right place, "forward" would not be the action. Despite it somehow getting named "Port Forwarding", the rules don't forward anything – they rewrite (translate) packets, while the actual forwarding decision is done elsewhere – so the action would be something like "DNAT - Rewrite to specific destination IP or port".

Thanks! The wording is really confusing. I added the rule and now when I ping the device, it's responding from the internal IP: 64 bytes from 10.150.42.7: icmp_seq=96 ttl=64 time=0.812 ms (DIFFERENT ADDRESS!) Is it possible to have the router rewrite the source IP in the response as well? Also, when I try to access the server in the browser or using curl, there is no response coming back. If I use the internal IP it works, though. So it looks like while the packets are being forwarded to the right place, there does not seem to be a path back.

For reference, the configuration: Match Incoming IPv4, protocol ICMP, TCP, UDP From lan To this device IP 100.76.72.54 port 1-1024 (I also tried selecting "Any" in protocol, but it had the same result). Action Forward to lan IP 10.150.42.7.

The router will automatically rewrite the source IP in the response – but only as long as the response goes through the router. In your case, both hosts are in the same subnet, which results in the response bypassing the router. To avoid this you need to rewrite the source IP of the request as well, and that's what the snat rule ("NAT hairpinning" / "NAT loopback") is for.

Not sure if I can follow you – If I add a SNAT rule, this will rewrite the address for all packets coming from 10.150.42.7, not only the ones that were sent to 100.76.72.54 and rewritten. Nevertheless, I added the rule but the ping responses are still coming from 10.150.42.7 and not the 100.* address. This is what I configured: Match Forwarded IPv4 and IPv6 From any zone, IP 10.150.42.7 To lan, Action Statically rewrite to source IP 100.76.72.54. Note that some devices use the internal DNS resolver and some use the external one so I can't rewrite all packets unconditionally.

I've re-read your comment and it looks like I misread the sentence "To avoid this you need to rewrite the source IP of the request as well". So I need to rewrite it to the router IP so that it's routed through the router?

Yes, again, the SNAT or MASQ rule needs to be applied to the requests, not to the responses.

I'm not understanding, though. Would you mind explaining? Why does the source address need to be changed on the requests? What does it need to be? My understanding is this: request ----> router ---- change destination address from 100.76.72.54 to 10.150.42.7 ------> server and then, it should be response (server) ----> router ---- change source address from 10.150.42.7 to 100.76.72.54 ----> client. The traffic will be passing through the router anyway, otherwise, how would the firewall be able to inspect the traffic and act upon it?

"The traffic will be passing through the router anyway" – no, that's the point; it will not. Traffic between hosts in the same subnet does not pass through the router. (When the sending host knows that the destination is on the same subnet, it'll send the packets directly to the recipient's MAC address and not to the router's MAC, and the packets go straight through the switch/bridge.) Therefore the router's firewall isn't able to inspect the traffic and change the response's source address, leading to the results you're seeing.

In other words, same-subnet DNAT always results in triangular traffic – even though the 'forward' traffic (request from client to server) goes through the router, the 'return' traffic does not. Rewriting the source IP address of the requests is needed to trick the server into replying through the router (as it thinks it's replying to the router), which gives the router's firewall the opportunity to undo DNAT and rewrite the source address of the responses (which it will do automatically once it actually gets to see the traffic).
